# not obvious Monotonicity of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be the function defined by

$$f(x) = e^{2x}-6e^x+4x+5$$

Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $(u_n)$ be the sequence of general term

$$u_n=F\left( \dfrac 1n -1\right)-F\left( \dfrac{1}{n+1}-1\right)$$

I'm having trouble with showing that $(u_n)$ is strictly increasing.

Some facts about $f$ :

- $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$
- $f$ is negative on $(-\infty,0]$

I tried the MVT but the order don't go well.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Did you try explicitly computing such an $F$ in order to calculate the value of $u_n$?

Comment: I started but not finished (hoping to get shorter, better ways) because calculations seem not to be promising

Comment: Also note that $u_n = \int_{-1+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{-1+\frac{1}{n}} f(x) \ dx$. Since $f$ is increasing, you can use the endpoints to find upper and lower bounds for $u_n$.